# SharePoint Search Service is not working

Tags: sharepoint-2007, windows-server-2008

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 with collaboration portal template on Windows Server 2008. When I use the following function from Central Administration from Application Management -> search -> Manage Search Service, I met with the following error message, any ideas what is wrong?

The search service is currently offline. Visit the Services on Server page in SharePoint Central Administration to verify whether the service is enabled. This might also be because an indexer move is in progress.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1):

This can happen for a variety of reasons. e.g. Search is infact moving/setting up the indexer, patch levels are different in the farm, etc. Rather than attempt to list all and their fixes, please see the links below:

http://msmvps.com/blogs/shane/archive/2009/04/13/fixing-moss-search.aspx

http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2009/02/24/the-search-service-is-currently-offline-visit-the-services-on-server-page-in-sharepoint-central-administration-to-verify-whether-the-service-is-enabled-this-might-also-be-because-an-indexer-move-is-in-progress.aspx

Comment: 1. For what the error message said -- "Services on Server page", I want to confirm with you that it means Central Administration -> Operations -> Topology and Services category -> Servers in the Farm. Is it correct? 2. If yes, which one(s) should I check for my issue? I find a couple of services listed here.

Comment: CA > Operations > Topology and Services > Services on Server to check services on a server (e.g. SharePoint Server Search Service which contains settings for turning up or off the query and index services on a server) also, you can click on your shared services administration link on the left of the CA and select 'edit properties' from the drop down arrow of the correct shared services provider to identify the index server for that ssp.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to start with the Event Logs on your Indexer. Also cross check your event logs with the Query servers.

Typically, if something is wrong, it would be logged there (or the ULS logs). But in this case start with the Event VWR... and reset search service on the indexer as well (using Service.msc)